# Workaround for error: "outside a vararg function near"

Tags: lua

While refractoring some lua (v5.3) code I didn't write, I came across an error for which I cannot find a good explanation/work-around. The error has to do with `vararg (...)`.

```
local function A()
   args = getargs(...)
   ... some more code
end

A()
```

I cannot paste the real code here since it will not work, but I hope you can see the problem from the example above: when I encapsulated `args = getargs(...)` inside `A()` I get the error:

`cannot use '...' outside a vararg function near '...'` 
I'm new to LUA but not new to programming so I find this error a bit strange. If `args` and `getargs()` are global, why am I getting this error and how do I get around it? The solution is not further nesting of `getargs()`.

Comment: You can only access `...` inside a function that has `...` as its argument (or some enclosing function has `...` as its argument).  There is nothing special here about `...`: for example, the same way inside `function(x)` you can access `x` but can't access `y` (as `y` is not an argument of `f`).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Ok. I understand. I naturally from your answer tried to pass `...` into A(...). Can `...` not be passed to nested functions?

Comment: Yes, `...` could be passed to inner functions.  For example, you can pass `y` to inner `function f(x)`, but inside `f` would be only `x`.  Think of `...` as usual variable name.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks. It works now :-) Appreciate the edification.

Comment: Ops! I just grasped that `...` is never an upvalue (probably, for performance reasons). It can't be inherited by inner function.

Answer (score 2):

Your *real* problem is that `A()` isn't vararg itself. This code shoul fix it:

```
local function A(...) -- Now this is vararg
   args = getargs(...)
   ... some more code
end

A()
```

P.S. why not make `args` local? Having both `arg` and `args` is confusing!

Comment: I just wrote an example code. So I didn't add any extra stuff.